# How do i nest angular dependencies in browserify?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I'm trying to create a base model (service) in angular, then extend it to another model, then trying to set up a dependency tree in browserify.  Browserify is not able to use my dependencies, and thinks that they are not defined. Here's what i have:

app.js:

```
var angular = require("angular");
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
var WidgetFactory = require("./WidgetFactory");

app.factory("WidgetFactory",WidgetFactory);
app.controller("DashboardController",["$scope", "WidgetFactory" ,function($scope, WidgetFactory) { 
... 
});
```

WidgetFactory.js:

```
var LineChartWidget = require ('./widget/LineChartWidget');
module.exports =  function(LineChartWidget) {
...
};
```

LineChartWidget.js:

```
var BaseWidget = require("./BaseWidget");

var LineChartWidget = function() {
    BaseWidget.apply(this, arguments);
}

LineChartWidget.prototype = new BaseWidget();

module.exports = LineChartWidget;
```

BaseWidget:

```
module.exports = function() {

    var BaseWidget = function(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    return BaseWidget;
};
```

But when i run the app, i get an error like this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LineChartWidgetProvider <- LineChartWidget <- WidgetFactory
```

I've been digging around all over with not much luck.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: If your app is not huge (tons and tons of modules), I would avoid using browserify since Angular does a great job ad modularizing its components and offering ways to expose data to each controller via APIs created by  factories. All you need to do is concat your JS files into one and your need for browserify is gone. This is a lot of complexity to work with unless you have a massive app to contend with.

Comment: thanks Ben.  I have previously built out this same application structure using requirejs and backbonejs, and the ability to nest dependencies was pretty straightforward.  The app is actually pretty big, with a lot of inheritance required.  Being new to angularJS and browserify, I'm sure there is just something obvious that i might just be missing.  I just can't seem to figure out why the line widget is not getting injected properly.